# Mockito - Returning the first element of a list passed into method

Tags: java, mockito

I have the following method that I'm trying to mock.

`public T myFunction(List<T>);`

Is it possible for Mockito to return the first element of the list?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Of course. Just specify it in the behavior recording :

```
List<Foo> list = ...;
Mockito.when(myMock.myFunction(list))
       .thenReturn(list.get(0));
```

Note that the mock will return the element specified at the time where the mock behavior is recorded.
If you want to return the first element contained in the list at runtime, you should probably use `when().then(Answer)` in this way :

```
List<Foo> list = ...;
Mockito.when(myMock.myFunction(list))
       .then(invocation ->                               
              ((List<Foo>) invocation.getArguments()[0])).get(0));
```

Comment: Quick and precise, and room for others!

Comment: This worked for me. I needed the element from the list at runtime.

Answer (score 1):

To get the first element of the `List` passed to the method:

```
when(whatever.myFunction(anyList()))
        .then(invocation -> invocation.getArgumentAt(0, List.class).get(0));
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding to the answer of davidxxx, you can also use [thenAnswer](http://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.18.3/org/mockito/Mockito.html#answer_stubs) instead of thenReturn to stub methods

```
Mockito.when(myMock.myFunction(anyList()))
       .thenAnswer(new Answer(){
     Object answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) {
         Object[] args = invocation.getArguments();
         List mock = (List)invocation.getMock();
         return mock.get(0);
     }
});
```

Comment: If you are using Java 8, Jespers answer is better. I'll still leave this here for people stuck on older versions.

Comment: In fact the two ways may produce a different effect. I updated my answer to illustrate that. I think that according to the OP requirement, the one or the other is suitable. In a general way, `then(Answer)` is more  verbose but more powerful. So I would favor this way only as required.

Answer (score 1):

All the answers are technically correct ... but giving a different perspective: don't create complicated tests!

Keep in mind that you only want to do "minimal control". You create a test setup, do something, check/verify results.

In that sense: consider to not return something based on inputs. Rather **expect** a specific input, and return a fixed, hard coded value.

The fact that you *can* program mocks to act like "programs doing a job" doesn't mean you *should* do that.

The only good reason would be if you have many similar test cases, and this additional complexity actually improves the quality of your test code.

Comment: The "reason" has talked :)